# gson serialize a non standard typed field

Tags: java, gson

I have a json which I would like to convert to PoJo and back. The format is like:

```
{
"name": "abc",
"othernames":{"x":"y", "z": 0}
}
```

Sometimes other instances are like:

```
{
"name": "abc",
"othernames":[{}]
}
```

How do I map this to a custom POJO class? I am finding the `othernames` part which sometimes is a `JsonObject` and some other times `JsonArray` a bit tricky.

I tried `MyCustomJsonAdapter`, but did not get far.

Comment: Where do you get this JSON from? Server? If yes, check their JSON schema and see what is mentioned there. If something is different that what is mentioned there, raise an issue with that team.